# How do I turn tld.com/bures/oceanfront into tld.com/articles/view/bures/oceanfront in Kohana?

Tags: php, kohana

I'm using Kohana 2.3.2

Most, if not all, of the links on my site are to articles.

My controller is called Articles, and I have a method titled View. I don't want to prefix all my links with /articles/view/, so I'd like to set a default controller to handle all files.

I've looked into using a default router, which made tld.com use the Articles controller. However, when I try and access something like /bure/oceanfront/, I get Kohana's 404 Error.

I have looked at [this article](http://learn.kohanaphp.com/2008/08/22/serving-static-pages/), but I believe it is outdated as the examples given are always error'ing (also see comments which point this out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now:

```
Event::add('system.post_routing' ,'call_fallback_page');



function call_fallback_page() {
        Router::$controller = 'Articles';
        Router::$method = 'index';
        Router::$controller_path = APPPATH.'controllers/articles.php';
}
```

Derived from the tutorial in the question.